# How to select spelling language in Windows Live Mail?

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-mail

I have Windows installed in English but I write most of my emails in Portuguese, when I'm writing most of the words are not English obviously so they get underlined in red, how can I choose the Language I'm writing in?

Comment: [See this article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/18158/windows-live-mail-2011-add-a-second-language-to-the-spell-checking-feature/)

Comment: [You may have to add a LIP](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Moab points to setting the default language is done in the mail options, but changing the language you're writing in when you write in more than one is not obvious to see:

- To set the default language:

First go to the mail options:

[image: WLMail options]

There install the language you want and set it as default (`Spelling`tab):

[image: Installing new languages]

- To change among languages once installed:

This can be more tricky, basically Windows Live Mail interprets the language you're writing in according to Windows language settings (!!!). So first you need to add more languages to Windows:

1. Go to the Control Panel and select to change keyboard languages:

   [image: Control Panel]
2. Add the languages you use there, or the ones you'd like to have:

   [image: Adding languages]
3. Accept the changes, you'll see that there is a language bar near the system tray.

   [image: Language selector]

That's what you have to use to make Windows Live Mail correct the language you want. I know WLMail developers made a wrong choice there because the force people to have that bar or at least to have more than one keyboard language set in the system in order to change the spell checker language, but as far as I know this is the only way.

Example:

[image: Wrong English words]
[image: Right Spanish words]

Comment: Thank you, that works, but I don't like that bar there. And mine doesn't look like yours, has a keyboard there next to the language name. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a Windows Live Mail message opened, you can switch among installed languages by simply hitting: ***ALT + Left SHIFT***

In order to install languages follow the detailed explanation provided by Xandy in the answer: https://superuser.com/a/502746/31927